# CouchDb view indexing while concurrent operations occur

Tags: couchdb

I understand that a request to a view will result in a update of its index.

However, how is this handled when other operations are performed against the db during this index. For instance, someone could update a doc that is part of that view. Or they could add a doc to that db which could impact the view being indexed? I cannot find information on this, does anyone know more?

Comment: Any document changes will fall at the end of the sequence of changes, so it won't impact your view until it finishes "catching up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what dominic commented, unless you explicitly ask couchdb won't return a view that's in the process of being updated until it's finished. If your database handles a lot of changes, this can really be a performance drag.

The stale [query option](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) can change this behavior.

- **stale=ok** -- provides the last value of the view and doesn't trigger an update.
- **stale=update_after** -- provides the last value of the view and then triggers an update.